# Tikz - draw bracket below a matrix of cell

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I have this array:

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz,convert={outext=.svg,command\unexpanded{pdf2svg \infile\space\outfile}},multi=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, matrix, fit, arrows.meta, shapes.misc, backgrounds}

\definecolor{customBlue}{HTML}{0063A2}
\definecolor{customAzure}{HTML}{C4EDF9}
\definecolor{customGreen}{HTML}{009053}
\definecolor{customPurple}{HTML}{812C7C}
\definecolor{customBrown}{HTML}{943227}
\definecolor{customViolet}{HTML}{3F367B}
\definecolor{customPink}{HTML}{DA0F70}
\definecolor{bracket}{HTML}{00A3DA}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1.5cm,]
    \matrix (C) [
      matrix of nodes,
      nodes={draw, minimum size=6mm},
      inner sep=6pt, outer sep=0pt,
      column sep=-\pgflinewidth
    ] at (0, 3){
      $\textcolor{customBlue}{2}, sl^1_0, ic^1_0$ &
      $\textcolor{orange}{31}, sl^1_1, ic^1_1$ &
      $\textcolor{customBrown}{102}, sl^1_2, ic^1_2$ &
      $\textcolor{customPink}{187}, sl^1_3, ic^1_3 $
      \\
    };
    \node[above=3pt of C-1-1]{$levels[1]$};
    \node[below=3pt of C-1-1]{$0$};
    \scoped[on background layer] {
      \node[fill=customAzure, inner sep=0mm, fit=(C-1-2.north east)(C-1-2.south west) ] {};
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I draw a bracket between node `2` and node `102`? The result is something like:
[image]

Comment: Take a look at `nicematrix` that allows to define table and then to use `TikZ` easily to add extra plots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is the Ti*k*Z library `decorations.pathreplacing` which have such decoration. You need to add this library, an optional style for the brace (look at my `tikzset`) and then just draw the brace (last `\draw`).

Complete code (your code with the above additions):

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, matrix, fit, arrows.meta, shapes.misc, backgrounds,
                decorations.pathreplacing} % <-- we need this library for the underbrace

\definecolor{customBlue}  {HTML}{0063A2}
\definecolor{customAzure} {HTML}{C4EDF9}
\definecolor{customGreen} {HTML}{009053}
\definecolor{customPurple}{HTML}{812C7C}
\definecolor{customBrown} {HTML}{943227}
\definecolor{customViolet}{HTML}{3F367B}
\definecolor{customPink}  {HTML}{DA0F70}
\definecolor{bracket}     {HTML}{00A3DA}

\tikzset%
{% this sytle provides the underbrace
   myunderbrace/.style={bracket,decorate,decoration={brace,raise=4mm,amplitude=6pt,mirror}},
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1.5cm,]
    \matrix (C) [
      matrix of nodes,
      nodes={draw, minimum size=6mm},
      inner sep=6pt, outer sep=0pt,
      column sep=-\pgflinewidth
    ] at (0, 3){
      $\textcolor{customBlue}{2}, sl^1_0, ic^1_0$ &
      $\textcolor{orange}{31}, sl^1_1, ic^1_1$ &
      $\textcolor{customBrown}{102}, sl^1_2, ic^1_2$ &
      $\textcolor{customPink}{187}, sl^1_3, ic^1_3 $
      \\
    };
    \node[above=3pt of C-1-1]{$levels[1]$};
    \node[below=3pt of C-1-1]{$0$};
    \scoped[on background layer] {
      \node[fill=customAzure, inner sep=0mm, fit=(C-1-2.north east)(C-1-2.south west) ] {};
    }
    \draw[myunderbrace] (C-1-1.south west) -- (C-1-3.south east);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the picture:
[image]

Of course, the `nicematrix` that suggests [projetmbc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/6880/projetmbc) is another good possibility.

Answer (score 1):

A wee bit more fancy (calligraphic) brace, used `matrix of math nodes`, local modifying cell style and use of labels enables to write simpler and shorter code:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz} % it load also xcolor
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,%
                    calligraphy,% had to be after decorations.pathreplacing
                matrix,
                positioning} 

\definecolor{customBlue}  {HTML}{0063A2}
\definecolor{customAzure} {HTML}{C4EDF9}
\definecolor{customBrown} {HTML}{943227}
\definecolor{customPink}  {HTML}{DA0F70}

\tikzset%
{% this style provides the underbrace
BC/.style args = {#1/#2}{% Brace Calligraphic
        decorate,
        decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=6pt,
        raise=#1},% for mirroring of brace
        thick,
        pen colour={#2}  },
every label/.style = {draw=none, inner sep=0pt, font=\small}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (C) [matrix of math nodes,
             nodes={draw, minimum size=6mm},
             inner sep=6pt, outer sep=0pt,
             column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
             ]
{
|[label={\textit{levels}[1]}, label=below:0]|
                                \textcolor{customBlue}{2},      sl^1_0, ic^1_0  &
  |[fill=customAzure]|          \textcolor{orange}{31},  sl^1_1, ic^1_1    &
\textcolor{customBrown}{102},   sl^1_2, ic^1_2  &
                                \textcolor{customPink}{187},    sl^1_3, ic^1_3  \\
};
\draw[BC=3ex/red]  (C-1-3.south east) -- (C-1-1.south west);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]