# Is it possible to typeset over and underbraces in NiceMatrix?

Tags: decorations, nicematrix, calligraphy

I am trying to draw matrices with overbraces and underbraces. This may be done with the assistance of node numbering and `\tikzset` to process a few options for the calligraphic braces.

According to how I do it, the output is as desired. However, such an option requires multiple brace widths and amplitudes for different lengths of braces. I would rather favor an elegant solution similar to `\SubMatrix` which adapts the width of the braces.

Related topics

[Is it possible to highlight every cell with counters `iRow` and `jCol` in `NiceTabular`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/622576/is-it-possible-to-highlight-every-cell-with-counters-irow-and-jcol-in-nicet)

[Tikz - draw bracket below a matrix of cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/610382/tikz-draw-bracket-below-a-matrix-of-cell/610401#610401)

[image]

This MWE helps in showing what I need

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}

\tikzset{
        BraceThick/.style = {decorate,
            decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=3.7pt,
                pre =moveto, pre  length=1.1pt,
                post=moveto, post length=1.1pt,
                raise=#1},
        thick, 
        pen colour=black},
        BraceThick/.default=0pt
}

\tikzset{
        BraceMirroredThick/.style = {decorate,
            decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=3.7pt,
                pre =moveto, pre  length=1.1pt,
                post=moveto, post length=1.1pt,
                mirror,
                raise=#1},
            thick,
            pen colour=black},
            BraceMirroredThick/.default=0pt,
}

\tikzset{
        BraceSemiThick/.style = {decorate,
            decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=2.5pt,
                pre =moveto, pre  length=1.1pt,
                post=moveto, post length=1.1pt,
                raise=#1},
        semithick, 
        pen colour=black},
        BraceSemiThick/.default=0pt
}

\tikzset{
        BraceMirroredSemiThick/.style = {decorate,
            decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=2.5pt,
                pre =moveto, pre  length=1.1pt,
                post=moveto, post length=1.1pt,
                mirror,
                raise=#1},
            semithick,
            pen colour=black},
            BraceMirroredSemiThick/.default=0pt,
}

\tikzset{
        BraceThin/.style = {decorate,
            decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=1.7pt,
                pre =moveto, pre  length=0.61pt,
                post=moveto, post length=0.61pt,
                raise=#1},
        thin, 
        pen colour=black},
        BraceThin/.default=0pt
}

\tikzset{
        BraceMirroredThin/.style = {decorate,
            decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=1.7pt,
                pre =moveto, pre  length=0.61pt,
                post=moveto, post length=0.61pt,
                mirror,
                raise=#1},
            thin,
            pen colour=black},
            BraceMirroredThin/.default=0pt,
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
    \NewDocumentCommand{\highlightNodes}{ O { } }
    {
        \foreach \i in {1,...,\arabic{iRow}}
        \foreach \j in {1,...,\arabic{jCol}}
        {
            \tikz [remember~picture, overlay] 
            \node [opacity=0.21] at (\i.5-|\j.5) {\color{gray} \i , \j} ;
        }
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    E =
        \begin{bNiceArray}{>{\strut}l|l}[create-extra-nodes, margin, extra-margin=1pt]
            \Block{2-1}{E_1}    & 0                 \\
            \cline {2-2}
            & \Block{2-1}{E_2}  \\
            \cline {1-1}
            0                   &                   \\
        \CodeAfter
        {
            \begin{tikzpicture}[name suffix = -large]
                \draw[BraceSemiThick={0pt}] (1-1.north west) -- node[above=0pt] {$C_1$} (1-1.north east);
                \draw[BraceSemiThick={0pt}] (1-2.north west) -- node[above=0pt] {$C_2$} (1-2.north east);
                \draw[BraceMirroredThin={0pt}] (3-1.south west) -- node[below=0pt] {$C_1$} (3-1.south east);
                \draw[BraceMirroredThin={0pt}] (3-2.south west) -- node[below=0pt] {$C_2$} (3-2.south east);
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \highlightNodes
        }
        \end{bNiceArray}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

**Edit**

It may seem that overbraces and underbraces look fine. However, we may add the following

```
\vspace{11mm}
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{bNiceArray}{ccc|c}[margin, create-extra-nodes]
        \Block[fill=Coral3]{3-3}<\large>{Z} &               &   &   0   \\
        & \hspace*{1cm} &   & \Vdots \\
        &               &   &   0    \\ \hline
        0            &    \Cdots     & 0 &   0
        \CodeAfter
        {
            \begin{tikzpicture}[name suffix = -large]
                \draw[BraceThick={0pt}] (1-1.north west) -- node[above=0pt] {$C_1$} (1-3.north east);
                \draw[BraceThick={0pt}] (1-4.north east) -- node[right=0pt] {$C_2$} (3-4.south east);
                \draw[BraceMirroredThin={0pt}] (4-4.south east)-- node[right=0pt] {$C_4$} (4-4.north east);
                \draw[BraceMirroredThick={0pt}] (4-1.south west)-- node[below=0pt] {$C_3$} (4-3.south east);
            \end{tikzpicture}
            %           \highlightNodes
        }
        \highlightNodes
    \end{bNiceArray}
    \mathstrut
\end{equation*}

\vspace{11mm}
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{bNiceArray}{ccc|c}[margin, create-extra-nodes]
        \Block[fill=Coral3]{3-3}<\large>{Z} &               &   &   0   \\
        & \hspace*{1cm} &   & \Vdots \\
        &               &   &   0    \\ \hline
        0            &    \Cdots     & 0 &   0
        \CodeAfter
        {
            \begin{tikzpicture}[name suffix = -large]
                \draw[BraceThin={0pt}] (1-1.north west) -- node[above=0pt] {$C_1$} (1-3.north east);
                \draw[BraceThin={0pt}] (1-4.north east) -- node[right=0pt] {$C_2$} (3-4.south east);
                \draw[BraceMirroredThick={0pt}] (4-4.south east)-- node[right=0pt] {$C_4$} (4-4.north east);
                \draw[BraceMirroredThin={0pt}] (4-1.south west)-- node[below=0pt] {$C_3$} (4-3.south  east);
            \end{tikzpicture}
            %           \highlightNodes
        }
        \highlightNodes
    \end{bNiceArray}
    \mathstrut
\end{equation*}
```

We see get the following result

[image]

As you see, the choice of braces in one example looks fine, but for the other, it looks very ugly because braces are too thin. For `BraceMirroredThick` for C4, it does not even look like a brace altogether.

`\SubMatrix` adjusts its width (`thick`, `thin`, etc) and `amplitude` dynamically to look good.

Comment: Of course it is possible. In link which you show, describe how to do this. What is actually your problem? Why you define so many braces? I'm pretty shore, that one definition is sufficient ...

Comment: @Zarko. I added an example on how such braces are not very suitable for my work

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh: For the future please stop using backticks `` in the title because it never works and it just adds unnecessary distracting stuffs.

Answer (score 6):

LIke this?

[image]

Since `nicematrix` as well desired braces use `tikz` (and for final image need two or more compilation), I think that in your case is better to make a pure `tikz` solution:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}

\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,
                calligraphy,
                fit,
                matrix}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
BC/.style args = {#1/#2}{% Braces Calligraphic
        decorate,
        decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=2pt,
        pre =moveto, pre  length=1pt,
        post=moveto, post length=1pt,
        raise=#1,
              #2},% for mirroring of brace
        thick,
        pen colour={black}
        },
                        ]  
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,
             nodes={minimum height=2ex, minimum width=1.3em, inner sep=1pt, 
                    anchor=center, text=gray!50},
             column sep=4pt, row sep=1pt,
             left delimiter={[},right delimiter={]},
             inner xsep=0pt, inner ysep=1pt
             ]
{
1,1 & 1,2   & 1,3   & 1,4   \\
2,1 & 2,2   & 2,3   & 2,4   \\
3,1 & 3,2   & 3,3   & 3,4   \\
4,1 & 4,2   & 4,3   & 4,4   \\
};
\draw   (m-3-1.south west)  -- (m-3-4.south east)
        (m-1-3.north east)  -- (m-4-3.south east);
% braces
\draw[BC=2pt/ ] (m-1-1.north west) -- node[above=2pt] {$C_1$} (m-1-3.north east);
\draw[BC=8pt/ ] (m-1-4.north east) -- node[right=9pt] {$C_2$} (m-3-4.south east);
\draw[BC=2pt/mirror] (m-4-1.south west) -- node[below=2pt] {$C_3$} (m-4-3.south east);
\draw[BC=8pt/mirror] (m-4-4.south east) -- node[right=9pt] {$C_4$} (m-4-4.north east);
%
\node[fill=Coral3, semitransparent, fit=(m-1-1) (m-3-3),
      inner sep=0pt] {};
\draw[very thick, line cap=round, dash pattern=on 0pt off 2\pgflinewidth] 
        (m-1-4) node {0} -- (m-4-4) node {0} -- (m-4-1) node {0};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note: above image you can insert in math environment. Also, for showed result is sufficuet one compilation of MWE.

Answer (score 2):

The version 6.4 of `nicematrix` (2021/11/23) provides new commands `\OverBrace` and `\UnderBrace` available in the `\CodeAfter` to address that kind of situation. The braces are braces of standard LaTeX (that is to say constructed with the current mathematical font) and not braces of Tikz.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\highlightNodes}{ O { } }
{
    \foreach \i in {1,...,\arabic{iRow}}
    \foreach \j in {1,...,\arabic{jCol}}
    {
        \tikz [remember~picture, overlay] 
        \node [opacity=0.21] at (\i.5-|\j.5) {\color{gray} \i , \j} ;
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{bNiceArray}{ccc|c}[margin, create-extra-nodes]
        \Block[fill=Coral3]{3-3}<\large>{Z} & &   &   0   \\
          & \hspace*{1cm} &   & \Vdots \\
          &               &   &   0    \\ \hline
        0 &    \Cdots     & 0 &   0
        \CodeAfter
        \highlightNodes
        \OverBrace[shorten,yshift=1mm]{1-1}{4-3}{C_{1}}
        \UnderBrace[shorten]{4-1}{4-3}{C_{3}}
    \end{bNiceArray}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

As usual with `nicematrix`, you need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]