# Drawing complex nested brackets, horizontally curled

Tags: brackets

I wanted to input those nested brackets in this pattern on a portrait-oriented page, which means they are supposed to be upright:

[image]

Any idea how to implement this?

UPDATE:
I actually lost hope in doing it horizontally so I switched to the normal ones, here is the code I used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

    \begin{document}
    
    \[
        \begin{aligned}
            & \text{3D-Space browsed} \\
            & \begin{cases}
                & \text{Plane 1 browsed} \\
                & \begin{cases}
                    & \begin{aligned}
                        & \begin{cases}
                            & \text{Level 7 top} \\
                            & \text{Level 7 bottom}
                        \end{cases} \\
                        & \begin{cases}
                            & \text{Level 7 top} \\
                            & \text{Level 7 bottom}
                        \end{cases}
                    \end{aligned}
                \end{cases}
                \quad
                \text{Plane 2  browsed} \\
                & \begin{cases}
                    & \begin{aligned}
                        & \begin{cases}
                            & \text{Level 7 top} \\
                            & \text{Level 7 bottom}
                        \end{cases} \\
                        & \begin{cases}
                            & \text{Level 7 top} \\
                            & \text{Level 7 bottom}
                        \end{cases}
                    \end{aligned} \\
                    & \begin{cases}
                        & \text{Level 7 top} \\
                        & \text{Level 7 bottom}
                    \end{cases}
                \end{cases}
            \end{cases}
        \end{aligned}
    \]
    
    \end{document}
```

But it gives an unusual output:

[image: I highlighted the places that are not as they should be]

also, two things are still left for me:

1. The linking curves between increments
2. The dots signaling the continuation of the pattern.

Any input would be appreciated.
Also, I checked the links provided by Zarko but my dumb brain did not know how to incorporate the code.

Comment: What you try so far? Please show this. Where you stuck? Are only curly braced the problem?

Comment: I could not do it horizontally at all. All I did was getting a simple vertical bracket. 
I am new to this so I may sound a bit too much of a noob, I am sorry.

Comment: Anyway, show what you try so far. After then we can easily help you. Now we haven't any information about your document and how showed picture is/should be inserted or written within.

Comment: See if answers  on https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/491915/ or  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/610382/ can help you.

Comment: I somehow beginning to get it, but I do not know how deep I can nest the braces. I will keep trying and see what comes up.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119876/11604

Answer (score 8):

You can do horizontal braces with `\overbrace` or `\underbrace`, as long as the braced sections are properly nested. For arrows connecting different parts of the drawing, see [How to add arrow in equations and matrix?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361392/110998).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  \overbrace{
    \overbrace{
      \overbrace{
        \begin{array}[t]{l}
          \text{Level 7 top} \\
          \text{Level 7 bottom}
        \end{array}
      }
      \overbrace{
        \begin{array}[t]{l}
          \text{Level 7 top} \\
          \text{Level 7 bottom}
        \end{array}
      }
    }^{\text{Plane 1 browsed}}
    \overbrace{
      \overbrace{
        \begin{array}[t]{l}
          \text{Level 7 top} \\
          \text{Level 7 bottom}
        \end{array}
      }
      \overbrace{
        \begin{array}[t]{l}
          \text{Level 7 top} \\
          \text{Level 7 bottom}
        \end{array}
      }
      \overbrace{
        \begin{array}[t]{l}
          \text{Level 7 top} \\
          \text{Level 7 bottom}
        \end{array}
      }
    }^{\text{Plane 2 browsed}}
  }^{\text{3D-Space browsed}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

This answer shows how to arrange the braces vertically. Note that the `cases` environment does the alignments, so you don't need `aligned`.
For arrows connecting different parts of the drawing, see [How to add arrow in equations and matrix?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361392/110998).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  \text{3D-Space browsed}
  \begin{cases}
    \text{Plane 1 browsed}
    \begin{cases}
       \begin{cases}
          \text{Level 7 top} \\
          \text{Level 7 bottom}
       \end{cases} \\
       \begin{cases}
          \text{Level 7 top} \\
          \text{Level 7 bottom}
       \end{cases}
    \end{cases}\\
    \text{Plane 2  browsed}
    \begin{cases}
       \begin{cases}
          \text{Level 7 top} \\
          \text{Level 7 bottom}
       \end{cases} \\
       \begin{cases}
          \text{Level 7 top} \\
          \text{Level 7 bottom}
       \end{cases}\\
       \begin{cases}
          \text{Level 7 top} \\
          \text{Level 7 bottom}
       \end{cases}
    \end{cases}
  \end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .. a lot

Answer (score 1):

Thank to the help of @gernot, I created the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\usepackage[margin=0.5cm]{geometry} % Set the margin to 1cm on all sides

\newcommand{\bigvdots}{\scalebox{1.5}{$\vdots$}}
\begin{document}

\[
  \text{(u,v,w) space browsed}
  \begin{cases}
    \text{$(k=1)$ $1_{st}$ plane browsed}
    \begin{cases}
    \text{$(j=1)$}
       \begin{cases}
          \text{$(i=1): n=1\tikzmark{0}$}\\
          \text{$(i=2): n=2\tikzmark{1}$}\\
          \vdots\\
          \text{$(i=I): n=I\tikzmark{2}$}\\
       \end{cases} \\\\
       \text{$(j=2)$}
       \begin{cases}
          \text{$(i=1): n=1 + I\tikzmark{3}$}\\
          \text{$(i=2): n=2 +I$}\\
          \vdots\\
          \text{$(i=I): n=2I$}\\
       \end{cases} \\
       \vdots\\
      \text{$(j=J)$}
       \begin{cases}
          \text{$(i=1): n=1 -I+IJ$}\\
          \vdots\\
          \text{$(i=I): n=IJ\tikzmark{4}$}\\
       \end{cases}
    \end{cases}
    \\\\
    \text{$(k=2)$ $2_{nd}$ plane browsed}
    \begin{cases}
    \text{$(j=1)$}
       \begin{cases}
          \text{$(i=1): n=1 + IJ\tikzmark{5}$}\\
          \vdots\\
          \text{$(i=I): n=I + IJ$}\\
       \end{cases} \\
       \vdots\\
      \text{$(j=J)$}
       \begin{cases}
          \text{$(i=1): n=1-I+2IJ$}\\
          \vdots\\
          \text{$(i=I): n=2IJ$}\\
       \end{cases}
    \end{cases}
    \\\\
\bigvdots\\\\
    \text{$(k=K)$ $K_{th}$ plane browsed}
    \begin{cases}
    \text{$(j=1)$}
       \begin{cases}
          \text{$(i=1): n=1-IJ+IJK$}\\
          \vdots\\
          \text{$(i=I): n=I-IJ+IJK$}\\
       \end{cases} \\
       \vdots\\
      \text{$(j=J)$}
       \begin{cases}
          \text{$(i=1): n=1 -I+KIJ$}\\
          \vdots\\
          \text{$(i=I): n=IKJ$}\\
       \end{cases}
    \end{cases}
  \end{cases}
\]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, bend left=45, -latex, blue]
  \draw[rounded corners=5pt] ([xshift=1ex, yshift=1ex]pic cs:0) --  node[right, xshift=6ex, yshift=-1.7ex] {Increment i} ++(1,0) |- ([xshift=1ex,  yshift=1ex]pic cs:1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, -latex, red]
  \draw[rounded corners=5pt]([xshift=1ex,yshift=1ex]pic cs:2) --  node[right, xshift=6ex, yshift=-3.8ex] {Increment j} ++(1,0) |-([xshift=1ex, yshift=1ex]pic cs:3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, -latex, green]
  \draw[rounded corners=5pt] ([xshift=1ex, yshift=1ex]pic cs:4) --  node[right, xshift=6ex, yshift=-3.8ex] {Increment k} ++(1.2,0) |- ([xshift=1ex, yshift=0.5ex]pic cs:5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which produces the following result:

[image: Execution of the MWE]

Which answers my question. However, there is an issue I still need to address:
For the text behind each bracket, I want to make it break a line while standing centered vertically around the middle of the curly brace. Is there a way to do so?